# What does it mean to be contaminated until the evening after immersion?

Tags: halacha, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

If someone is a baal keri [they had a seminal emission], and they clean themselves, they remain contaminated until evening ([Lev 15:16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0315.htm#16)). What does that entail? Does being contaminated until evening mean they can't go to work without the fear of contaminating others?

Comment: Hello Romaion, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for your first question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: When you write "immediatly cleaning themselves" do you mean immersing in a mikve? Or cleaning in the modern sense of the word? Some answers below assume you mean immersing in a mikve (ritual bath)

Comment: I'm really not sure what I originally meant - I mean, I guess I'm just searching how a person, in today's era, is supposed to de-contaminate himself after an emission: because the Torah says that anything he touches becomes contaminated.

Comment: @Romaion Different impurities and different objects have different ways of becoming pure, and also have different ways they transmit impurity to other objects. Consider learning https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tohorot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After immersion from a first-order impurity, a person or vessel remains somewhat impure until sundown (called "Tevul Yom"). (Rambam, Shar Avot HaTumah 10:1)

A Tevul Yom who touched Terumah renders it third-order impure, and if they touch Temple sacrifices they render them fourth-order impure (ibid. :3). A Tevul Yom does not affect people, vessels, standard food (Rambam, Tumat Ochlin 7:7), second-tithe food (Rambam, Mishkav uMoshav 5:6), or ashes of the Red Heifer (Rambam, Parah 1:13).

Additionally, unlike other impurities, body fluids of a Tevul Yom are pure (Rambam, Avot HaTumah, 10:6). A Tevul Yom is prohibited rabbinically from entering even the outer parts of the Temple, but they may go on the Temple mount (Rambam, Biat Mikdash 3:6). A Kohein who is a Tevul Yom is still fully prohibited from serving in the Temple (ibid. 4:4).

Answer (score 1):

Even in Temple times, from immersion until nightfall their status is called *tvul yom.* They're just ever-so-slightly "impure" enough that they can't touch holy food such as *terumah* or sacrifices, but touching people wouldn't do anything.

Today this is all pretty much a moot point anyhow, and the best practice (halachically and psychologically) is to get back to a normal routine right away.